# Obtener valor máximo de cada partición SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día compañeros, tengo una tabla con información de clientes, para distinguir a cada cliente utilizo el campo "ident_num", también cuento con un campo de fecha "registered_date", debido a que hay clientes repetidos con el mismo "ident_num" necesito obtener solo un cliente (de cada cliente repetido) y que sea el último registro agregado (la fecha más cercana a la actual). Mi idea fue realizar una "Partición" e intentar obtener el último registro de cada uno... Pero no he podido obtener el resultado que quiero:

Utilizo el siguiente script para obtener aquellos clientes repetidos (campo ident_num):

```
Select ident_num, COUNT(*)
from a2AuthClients 
group by ident_num
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
order by ident_num asc
```

El siguiente script es una idea de lo que realizo para obtener el último de cada cliente repetido, sin embargo no he podido obtener el resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ident_num, registered_date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ident_num ORDER BY registered_date DESC) rn
FROM a2AuthClients
)as b 
where b.rn >= 1
```

Si me pueden ayudar con alguna idea se los agradecería.
Saludos.

Comment: Y si solo agrupas por cliente y utilizas MAX() para el ultimo registro creado?

Comment: Ya lo he intentado... existe la posibilidad de que lo haya hecho con la sintaxis incorrecta... Si me pudieras ayudar con un ejemplo de como se aplicaría en mi ejemplo te lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿Que problema tienes con  tu consulta? ¿No debiera ser `where b.rn = 1` en todo caso?

Comment: No seria un MAX() nomas? SELECT ident_num, MAX(registered_date) FROM a2AuthClients GROUP BY ident_num

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo solo deseo los datos de aquellos usuarios que estén repetidos por el campo "ident_num". Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el siguiente ejemplo puedes obtener el cliente mas reciente, aunque este repetido el ident_num. Trata de no utilizar distinct, ya que baja el rendimiento de tu consulta. Si usas distinct que solo sea una ultima opción.

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE (
    ident_num INT
    ,registered_date DATETIME
    ,client_name VARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 1
    ,'01/01/2018'
    ,'Cliente1'

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 2
    ,'01/02/2018'
    ,'Cliente1'

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 1
    ,'02/02/2018'
    ,'Cliente1'

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 3
    ,'01/03/2018'
    ,'Cliente1'

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 2
    ,'15/03/2018'
    ,'Cliente1'

INSERT INTO @Tabla
SELECT 2
    ,'20/04/2018'
    ,'Cliente1'

SELECT MAX(registered_date) AS registered_date
    ,ident_num
FROM @Tabla
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY ident_num  --Aqui facilmente puedes obtener el ultimo registro de cada cliente

SELECT *
FROM @Tabla a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(registered_date) AS registered_date
        ,ident_num
    FROM @Tabla
    WHERE 1 = 1
    GROUP BY ident_num
    ) x ON a.ident_num = x.ident_num
    AND a.registered_date = x.registered_date -- Con la consulta anterior puedes hacer un inner join
                                              --a la tabla de clientes para así obtener los datos de la tabla clientes solo del
                                              --cliente mas reciente
```

Para obtener solo los repetidos:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Tabla a
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(registered_date) AS registered_date
        ,ident_num, count(ident_num) as Repetidos
    FROM @Tabla y
    WHERE 1=1
    GROUP BY ident_num) y ON a.ident_num=y.ident_num and y.Repetidos >1  and a.registered_date=y.registered_date
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo en la pregunta especifiqué que solo deseo los datos de los usuarios repetidos y no de todos los clientes. Que debería cambiar para obtener los datos de solo esos usuarios?. Saludos compañero.

Comment: Ya hice el cambio en la respuesta, ahí puedes revisarlo. Saludos.

Comment: Te comento que me muestra 14,000 registros, y con mi consulta para ver cuantos hay repetidos me muestra 13,700 registros, alguna idea de por qué la diferencia de esos 300 registros?

Comment: Corrección a mi comentario anterior, estoy verificando y me muestra usuarios que no están repetidos, ya que les hago un select por "ident_num" y me muestra solo un registro.

Comment: si agregaste la condición que Y.Repetidos > 1 ?

Comment: Si lo agregué, básicamente hice un copy/paste a tu código y cambié el nombre de la tabla.

Comment: Corrección de nuevo, estoy haciendo algo mal en mi consulta, discúlpame XD... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funcionó correctamente. Saludos.

Comment: Me ayudarías solo a comprender el "Where 1=1", que hace exactamente?... es como para forzar a usar el group by?

Comment: Normalmente lo dejo, por referencia si debes agregar alguna condición ya sabes donde hacerlo. La consulta funciona sin ese where. Ahora bien hay casos donde si te sirve para forzar una consulta.

Answer (score 1):

entiendo que lo que quieres es que de los clientes con `ident_num` iguales, te quieres quedar con el cliente con mayor fecha o fecha más actual.

Puedes probar algo así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT A.ident_num,
              B.registered_date,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ident_num ORDER BY A.ident_num) AS RN
       FROM (SELECT ident_num FROM a2AuthClients GROUP BY ident_num HAVING COUNT(ident_num) > 1) AS A
       INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT ident_num, MAX(registered_date) AS registered_date 
              FROM a2AuthClients GROUP BY ident_num) B
        ON A.ident_num = B.ident_num) X
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo al realizar la consulta que les compartí para obtener los usuarios con "ident_num" repetidos me muestra un aproximado de 13K registros y tu consulta me muestra más de 200K. Solo deseo aquellos que se repiten como tu mencionas... Alguna idea al respecto?. Saludos compañero.

Comment: @BDOM He editado la respuesta a ver si te sirve. He añadido una agrupación de `ident_num` tomando sólo aquellos que se repiten. Puedes hacerlo en la sub select A o en B.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta compañero, también funciona correctamente tu consulta, gracias por tu tiempo :D